# Remove selectionsColumn from Columns dropdown in admin grid

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, custom, uicomponent

In my custom admin grid I have checkboxes , I added them like this:

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">transaction_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</selectionsColumn>
```

And now there is an item for this column in "Columns dropdown" with empty label:
[image]

How can I remove it from this dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it disappeared after I removed this line from my grid xml

```
 <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

which was located inside "columns" and then "argument" tags